# What's the best approach to making a basic user- admin user application?

Tags: android-studio

I am creating an event app basically, where an admin can add events and then users can register to event. What I've created so far is a login register and account settings activities. I am not sure how to approach the different permissions for user and admin. The difference between those is that admin can create an event by pressing some button and basic user cannot. Do I create two different main menu's for that?

Also, How do I identify who is admin and who is a basic user? I was thinking that for admins(there would be like 1-2 admins in this app) I could manually create an account so that I would not need to create another register activity.